# C#. Слишком длинный строковый параметр

Tags: c#, ms-word

Заменяю текст в документе word. Пока текст короткий передаю в word, всё нормально работает. Сейчас попался текст длинной 1221 символ - вышла ошибка: "Слишком длинный строковый параметр".

```
Word.Range wRprim = app.Selection.Range;
wRprim.Find.Execute(FindText: "{word_prim}", ReplaceWith: prim_str);
```

Comment: [Find/Replace character limit workaround in VBA for Word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53154314/2881286) и [runtime error 5854 string parameter is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5050902/2881286) похоже ограничение word на 255 символов

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать промежуточную переменную. Например,

```
string s = "{word" + "_prim}";
wRprim.Find.Execute(FindText: s, ReplaceWith: prim_str);
```